# Remove Ruby and Rails from my system?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos

i got several problem runnings ruby and rails. I installed ruby via Macports. How to I remove everything and reinstall everything from the ground up?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To uninstall from MacPorts:

`port uninstall ruby`

I recommend installing rvm and using it to manage all of your ruby versions.  Start here:  http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/

Once you have it installed, reload your shell and type:

```
rvm install ruby-1.9.2
```

Once that is done, type

```
rvm use ruby-1.9.2 --default
```

This will replace your system ruby with the rvm 192 version.  Feel free to install any other versions and switch to them using `rvm list` and `rvm use`.

Comment: Thanks for hitting submit about 10 seconds before I planned to say the same things :p

Comment: fabian, note that even if you uninstall the MacPorts version of ruby you'll still have a system version installed.  That's fine, leave it.  Install and use rvm to change ruby to the version(s) you want to use.

Comment: I wrote a post covering installing with Mac OS X + RVM: http://ryanbigg.com/2011/06/mac-os-x-ruby-rvm-rails-and-you/

Answer (score 0):

For me this code worked very well    sudo apt-get autoremove ruby